# How to find the amount of shared extents on btrfs?

Tags: btrfs

What command can I use to see the amount of shared extents on a btrfs volume. Or better yet, what command gives me the logical size used along with the on-disk size of all extents together?

Comment: Anyone wanting to answer this, may want to read https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Data_Structures#btrfs_extent_inline_ref. Apparently no tool included in the btrfs-tools package includes something that shows this, or [maybe I'm wrong...](http://lwn.net/Articles/562440/)

Answer (score 1):

For any filesystem you can use the [filefrag](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/filefrag.8.html) command on each file individually.

To operate recursively you can pair this with the find command like so:

```
find <dirname> -type f -exec filefrag {} \;
```

---

You can also run [inspect-internal](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-inspect-internal.html):

```
btrfs inspect-internal dump-tree --extents <filesystemname>
```

to get a more technical look at the filesystem.